# React, getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') on some refreshes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple server that listens on port `8000` and all it does is to return the name of the files inside a directory in this format:

```json
{'Files': ['file1', 'file2', ...]}
```

I have a React app, that fetches the data using the `useEffect` hook and then places the response with the `useState` hook.

The problem is that, on the first try it works perfectly, and maybe on the second time as well, but when I refresh for the third time (or more) it just disappears! and I see an error message on the chrome devtools:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

The React code is:

```js
import './App.css';
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";


function App() {

    const [file, setFile] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const files = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/get_directory?dir=E:\\Learning\\LearningNetworking\\MD')
            const file_json = await files.json()
            setFile(file_json.File)
        }

        fetchData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                {file.map(file_name => <p>{file_name}<br/></p>)}
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I really don't know what's going on, maybe there's a race condition and the react app tries to render the list before fetching it? But doesn't the React `useEffect` hook knows when to fetch again and when not?

I tried using the nullish coalescing on this line:

```js
const file_json = await files.json() ?? []
```

instead of:

```js
const file_json = await files.json()
```

The server (if needed for debugging reasons) written in fastapi:

```py
from pathlib import Path

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware,
                   allow_origins=['*'])


@app.get('/get_directory')
def directory_tree(request: Request):
    path = request.query_params.get('dir', None)
    return {'Files': [file.name for file in Path(path).iterdir()]}
```

I'm pretty sure I've got something wrong here in my understanding of React, I am a newbie so I would appreciate your help! Any searches online did not find exactly this problem (maybe it's because I couldn't phrase the problem very well... sorry if it has been asked before!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is coming from your client code. As you defined it, initially, `file` is `undefined`. And because `useEffect`'s callback runs after the JSX is rendered, you are getting this error. One way to solve this issue is to initiate your state like this:

```
const [file, setFile] = useState([]);
```